# Custom Sorting in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oop, sorting, class-design

I have designed a Class for Parent Child relationship

```
  class Category
  {
    public string CatName;
    public string CatId;
    public IList<Category> childCategory = new List<Category>();

    public  void addChildCat(Category childCat)
    {
      this.childCategory.Add(childCat);
    }

    public Category SortedCategory(Category cat)
    {
      // Should return the sorted cat i.e topmost parent        
    }
}
```

Here by Parent will not have Catname or CatId, it will have Child Categories which has CatName, CatId as well as another Child Category List and it goes till "N" categories

1. Here I need to get the Top Parent with all the child categories sorted by CatName. Any ideas How this can be achieved?
2. Is my class design GOOD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because you have not a reference to the parent. You have to add a field:

```
public Category Parent { get; set; }
```

and modify the add method to set the parent:

```
public void addChildCat(Category childCat)
{
  childCat.Parent = this;
  this.childCategory.Add(childCat);
}
```

You need the parent to get the root:

```
public static Category SortedCategory(Category cat)
{
  // get the root
  var root = cat;
  while(root.Parent != null) root = root.Parent;

  return root.GetSorted();
}

private Category GetSorted()
{
  var sortedChildren = new List<Category>(childCategories).ConvertAll(c => c.GetSorted());
  sortedChildren.Sort((c1, c2) => c1.CatName.CompareTo(c2.Catname));

  return new Category { CatName = root.CatName, 
                        Catid = root.CatId,
                        childCategories = sortedChildren; }
}
```

Comment: Can pl explain me how sorting is related with public Category Parent { get; set; }?

Comment: Without the parent you cannot get the root.

Comment: Great!!! I got the point! can you pl explain me what happens with GetSorted(). I am new to lambda (i hope so)

Comment: I got few points, Looks like recursive, yet I am not sure how you perform CatName = root.CatName, Catid = root.CatId, using root!

Comment: It's creating a new sorted category object copying fields from the root - Object initialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) to keep track of the child categories instead.

Comment: Won't this prevent my Tree getting expanded?

Comment: nah, it's fine, you can use it like a normal list, the items are sorted by the key that's all

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this, we have a tree structure right? And what is the result you are expecting, the sorted children of the topmost parent (root)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
public string CatName;
public string CatId;
```

I would do:

```
 class Cat
 {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Id { get; set; }
 }
```

And instead of:

```
public Category SortedCategory(Category cat)
    {
      // Should return the sorted cat i.e topmost parent        
    }
```

I would do:

```
 var category = new List<Cat>
                               {
                                   new Cat() {Name = "cat1", Id = "123"},
                                   new Cat() {Name = "cat2", Id = "124"},
                                   new Cat() {Name = "cat3", Id = "125"},
                                   new Cat() {Name = "cat4", Id = "126"}
                               };


category.Sort(( cat1, cat2) =>  ((Convert.ToInt32(cat1.Id) > Convert.ToInt32(cat2.Id)) ? 1 : 0) );
```